# Combining jupyter/ipython kernels in notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

There are numerous [Jupyter Kernels](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages) available. I'm also aware of some projects for running one language embedded in another e.g. [rpy2](https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/). However, i'm interested to know if it's possible (or if there are plans) **to combine different kernels together in a single notebook?**

So say I would have one cell in python code, and another in scala code, the same way that I currently can have a code cell (press <kbd>y</kbd> on a cell) as well as a markdown cell <kbd>m</kbd>.

Ideally one should be able to pass variables back and forth, but for this question I'd just be looking to be able to have two different 'code cell' types, without them being aware of each other (so I could have for example a python variable assignment `x  = 1` and a scala `val x : Int = 2` and they wouldn't be aware of one another).

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible to manually switch kernels from cell to cell. I've tested going from Python to Julia to R. Works fine. HOWEVER, the namespaces are wiped clean so you would have to maintain state externally if you wanted to switch back and forth.

Wouldn't guarantee sane behavior though.  Don't know how you would automate the kernel switch

Comment: could you elaborate on how to do this, please?